# How can I solve Memory leak in GeneXus Ver. XEV1 Upgrade #8

Tags: genexus

There is a Web Panel that has a grid with 4000 pages; when paging the grid, memory usage increases indefinitely.How can I solve this problem?Please!

Comment: Hi, please contact GeneXus support  www.gxtechnical.com/assistedsupport . Seems you are having an issue that has already been fixed in a previous version of yours, so it may be that you have some installation issues. See http://www2.gxtechnical.com/portal/hgxppredirect.aspx?15,26,0,,,30864

Answer (score 0):

You have to limit the number of grid lines and control pagination with command Grid.GotoPage(&PageNumber) in the refresh event. This way will be read only the onscreen records.